# Ventilators and evaporative cooling

Tags: water, evaporation, meteorology

I've recently read that ventilators make sweat or water in your skin to be more likely to evaporate. How can that be the case? If the temperature does not increase, how can it provoke such an effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaporation is a type of vaporization that occurs on the surface of liquid (like water) as it changes into gas phase. Evaporation occurs almost at all temperatures (i.e. in all seasons) but the rate of evaporation of liquid (say water) depends on the humidity (amount of water vapor) of surrounding (ambient) air.

When ventilator runs it moves out of room the humid air which has absorbed relatively higher amount of water or sweat from your skin by evaporation and brings in the fresh air inside the room. This fresh air entered has relatively less humidity (i.e. water vapor) which increases the rate of evaporation of sweat or water from your skin because dry or less humid air can hold higher amount of water vapor. Thus ventilators help increase the rate of evaporation of sweat or water from your skin even if the temperature doesn't increase.